# Navigation View doesn't open different forms

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to implement a NavigationView in my UWP app. I followed a Microsoft tutorial to do so.

Here is the tutorial I followed: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/06/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/

I've checked that the textblock in each Views page is the exact same as both the item tag in the XAML code for the NavigationView element and the string in the code-behind.

//This is the C# code-behind

## region NavigationView event handlers

```
    private void nvTopLevelNav_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems)
        {
            if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "logFood")
            {
                nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(LogFood));
    }

    private void nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    private void nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
        {
            //put settings page here
        }
        else
        {

            TextBlock ItemContent = args.InvokedItem as TextBlock;
            if (ItemContent != null)
                switch (ItemContent.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    case "logFood":
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(LogFood));
                        break;

                    case "calculate":
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyNewPage));
                        break;

                    case "setNutritionGoals":
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SetGoals));
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

//This is the XAML code

```
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="logFood_NavViewItem" Icon="Edit" Content="Log Food" Tag="logFood"/>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="calculate" Icon="Calculator" Content="Calculate Nutrition Goals" Tag="calculate" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="saveGoals" Icon="Save" Content="Set Nutrition Goals" Tag="setNutritionGoals"/>

        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>
```

I expect to be able to navigate between the different XAML pages. However, when I press each button in the navigation view, the selected item is highlighted, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `InvokeItem` in `NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs` refers to the `Content` property of the `NavigationViewItem`.

For the `ItemContent` which is not working, the reason is due to he hasn’t put `TextBlock` in your `NavigationViewItem`. That’s why it’s always null.

if you need the Tag property, please modify the XAML like this:

```xml
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationViewItem Icon="Edit"  x:Name="logFood_NavViewItem">
        <TextBlock Tag="logFood">Log Food</TextBlock>
    </NavigationViewItem>
    ...
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

---

If you don't plan to modify XAML, you can modify your `nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked` function like this:

```cs
if (args.InvokedItem is string ItemContent)
{
    switch (ItemContent)
    {
        case "Log Food":
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(LogFood));
            break;

        case "Calculate Nutrition Goals":
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyNewPage));
            break;

        case "Set Nutrition Goals":
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SetGoals));
            break;
    }
}
```

Best regards.